# I can not change the URL of my new page during a redirect

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes

On symfony 3.4 I would like to call another function from my controller. The called function will have to redirect to a new page. I would like the URL of the page to be modified.

However, with the method I used, the page changes well, but not the URL.

The scheme was as follows:

1. Controller => Function => Display login form (twig)
2. Login form => Validation (POST METHOD)=> Controller => Function => Call other function => Display other page (and modification of the URL).

The URL is not changed, I do not understand.

Here is my code :

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Controller;

use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User;
use Site\PagesBundle\Entity\Information;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * Information controller.
 *
 * @Route("accueil")
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Accueil
     *
     * @Route("/", name="connexion_index")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager

        $listeInfos = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 1"); //Récupération d'une liste d'informations

        $user = new User(); //Initialisation de l'objet User
        $form = $this->createForm('Site\PagesBundle\Form\ConnexionType', $user); //Formulaire de création
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //Traitement si le formulaire est soumis ( Ajout du package dans la BDD )
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);

            $valide = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->authentifier($user->getIdentifiant(),$user->getPassword());
            dump($valide);

            if($valide == 1)
            {
                return $this->accueil($request);
            }

            else
            {
                return $this->render('@Pages/Default/connexion.html.twig',array(
                    'user' => $user,
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'listeInfos' => $listeInfos,
                ));
            }

            // On ajoute un package, donc on offre un téléchargement supplémentaire aux utilisateurs concernés
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('PagesBundle:User')->updateNbDDLAll("inc"); 

            //return $this->redirectToRoute('paquets_index'); // Redirection page de gestion de packages
        }



        return $this->render('@Pages/Default/connexion.html.twig',array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'listeInfos' => $listeInfos,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/index", name="accueil")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function accueil(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager

        $listeInfos = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 2"); //Récupération d'une liste d'informations

        return $this->render('@Pages/Default/accueil.html.twig',array(
            'listeInfos' => $listeInfos,
        ));
    }
}
```

**The change must happen here:**

```
if($valide == 1)
        {
            return $this->accueil($request);
        }
```

To

```
/**
     * @Route("/index", name="accueil")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function accueil(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager

        $listeInfos = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 2"); //Récupération d'une liste d'informations

        return $this->render('@Pages/Default/accueil.html.twig',array(
            'listeInfos' => $listeInfos,
        ));
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not redirecting to another path, but only returning a `view` within a controller `indexAction`. As the current url already corresponds to this `action` no change is made in the url. If you want to navigate to another path you must tell Symfony to do so.

```
if($valide == 1)
{
    return $this->redirectToRoute('accueil');
}
```

Your `accueil` function must then also be an `action`.

```
/**
 * @Route("/index", name="accueil")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function accueilAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //Récupération du manager

    $listeInfos = $em->getRepository('PagesBundle:Information')->getInformationsZone("Zone 2"); //Récupération d'une liste d'informations

    return $this->render('@Pages/Default/accueil.html.twig',array(
            'listeInfos' => $listeInfos,
        ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Oh yes I understand better now, and I completely forgot the notion of "action". Moreover, under what circumstances should I add "action" at the end of my method? Thank you !

Comment: Only when the method corresponds to a path in the url. More information can be found here: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing.html